# Springframework.data.jpa incompatibility with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject gives ClassCastExceptions on WAS 8.5.5.18

Tags: spring-data-jpa, cdi, javassist

I've seen this issue mentioned at a few posts here but I'm still posting this as i'm just not able to find the solution for my problem:

```
Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension_$$_jvste4_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl.join(WsComponentImpl.java:432)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCUList(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:1295)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:275)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationServerImpl.start(ApplicationServerImpl.java:252)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerHelper.startComponents(ContainerHelper.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.startComponents(ContainerImpl.java:627)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ContainerImpl.start(ContainerImpl.java:618)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ServerImpl.start(ServerImpl.java:540)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.bootServerContainer(WsServerImpl.java:325)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.start(WsServerImpl.java:238)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServerImpl.main(WsServerImpl.java:711)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.WsServer.main(WsServer.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.launchMain(WSLauncher.java:234)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.main(WSLauncher.java:96)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSLauncher.run(WSLauncher.java:77)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
        at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:340)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:282)
        at org.eclipse.core.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:981)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.launchEclipse(WSPreLauncher.java:424)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.bootstrap.WSPreLauncher.main(WSPreLauncher.java:177)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.exception.RuntimeWarning: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension_$$_jvste4_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:433)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:719)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1211)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1464)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:642)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1042)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:795)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$5.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2279)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5536)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5662)
        at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2284)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:436)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:379)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:127)
        at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$CUInitializer.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:985)
        at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:524)
        at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1892)
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: Failed to load webapp: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension_$$_jvste4_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:914)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:789)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:427)
        ... 18 more
Caused by: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.exception.WebAppNotLoadedException: Failed to load webapp: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension_$$_jvste4_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:186)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:904)
        ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.cdi.JpaRepositoryExtension_$$_jvste4_0 incompatible with javassist.util.proxy.ProxyObject
        at org.apache.webbeans.proxy.JavassistProxyFactory.createNormalScopedBeanProxy(JavassistProxyFactory.java:225)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.getReference(BeanManagerImpl.java:966)
        at org.apache.webbeans.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:285)
        at org.apache.webbeans.event.NotificationManager.fireEvent(NotificationManager.java:455)
        at org.apache.webbeans.container.BeanManagerImpl.fireEvent(BeanManagerImpl.java:469)
        at org.apache.webbeans.util.WebBeansUtil.fireProcessAnnotatedTypeEvent(WebBeansUtil.java:2657)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploySingleAnnotatedType(BeansDeployer.java:538)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deployFromClassPath(BeansDeployer.java:488)
        at org.apache.webbeans.config.BeansDeployer.deploy(BeansDeployer.java:171)
        at org.apache.webbeans.lifecycle.AbstractLifeCycle.startApplication(AbstractLifeCycle.java:124)
        at org.apache.webbeans.web.lifecycle.WebContainerLifecycle.startApplication(WebContainerLifecycle.java:77)
        at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.common.CommonLifeCycle.startApplication(CommonLifeCycle.java:106)
        at com.ibm.ws.webbeans.services.JCDIServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(JCDIServletContainerInitializer.java:85) at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initializeServletContainerInitializers(WebAppImpl.java:620)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:410)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
        at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:171)
        ... 21 more
```

---

When I try to deploy an application on websphere, I get the above exception and it fails to start.
There are other projects with similar dependencies which get deployed and also starts.
As per the posts I read similar to my problem, I tried the below:

- Exclude the javassist dependencies.
- ClassLoaderMode is also set to PARENT_LAST.

It seems to be issue with the javassist on WAS conflicting with the javassist in the jars shipped with my application jars.
I've commented out dependencies from my application which has javassist transitive dependencies and have also excluded them in the dependencies like :
hibernate-core:5.4.21.Final
org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:2.3.3.RELEASE

and added another entry for javassist version:3.21.0-GA as I got this version from the websphere team member from our project.

DEPENDENCY TREE is as below:

---

```
[INFO] +- com.myproject:jar:1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.7:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-orm:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.9.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.4.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.persistence:javax.persistence-api:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.10.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- antlr:antlr:jar:2.7.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction:jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec:jar:1.1.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.jboss:jandex:jar:2.1.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.activation:javax.activation-api:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate.common:hibernate-commons-annotations:jar:5.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.glassfish.jaxb:jaxb-runtime:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.glassfish.jaxb:txw2:jar:2.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.sun.istack:istack-commons-runtime:jar:3.0.7:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- org.jvnet.staxex:stax-ex:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.sun.xml.fastinfoset:FastInfoset:jar:1.2.15:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:jar:5.4.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:5:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-text:jar:1.9:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.20:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:0.0.6:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:0.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] +- javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:2.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] +- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:6.0.21.Final:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.2.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.db2:jcc:jar:11.1.4.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.db2:db2jcc_license_cisuz:jar:1.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:5.3.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:4.0.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:log4j2-impl:jar:2.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-slf4j-impl:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.9.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.lmax:disruptor:jar:3.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.interceptor:javax.interceptor-api:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.jms:javax.jms-api:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.websphere:recjava:jar:6.0.2.37:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.ibm.websphere:eablib:jar:6.0.2.37:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- javax.resource:javax.resource-api:jar:1.7.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- javax.transaction:javax.transaction-api:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.ibm.ims:imsico:jar:13.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.ibm.websphere.ws:marshall:jar:8.5.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.myotherproject:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:0.1.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:1.0.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.myotherproject:pom:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:0.0.22:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.code.gson:gson:jar:2.8.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:3.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.mikesamuel:json-sanitizer:jar:1.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.googlecode.owasp-java-html-sanitizer:owasp-java-html-sanitizer:jar:20181114.1:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:0.0.20:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:0.0.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.dom4j:dom4j:jar:2.1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- v:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.myotherproject:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.myotherproject:jar:0.0.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.myotherproject:jar:1.8:compile
[INFO] \- com.myotherproject:0.0.15:compile
[INFO]    +- javax.resource:connector-api:jar:1.5:compile
[INFO]    +- com.ibm.websphere:marshall:jar:7.0.0.19:compile
[INFO]    +- com.nordea.oss:copybook4java:jar:1.0.3:compile
[INFO]    \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.10:provided
```

**Question**:Kindly help if there's anything that I could try out as I've been stuck with this issue for weeks now.

Comment: As I have no access to WebSphere AS 8.5.5.18, I cannot check which Javassist version is used there. The only thing I do know is that it seems to be used for CDI in combination with Apache OpenWebBeans. Are you and your WS support team sure that it is 3.21.0-GA? Have you inspected the WebSphere libraries and verified the version number?

Comment: Actually the websphere team told me that its a conflict in the openweb beans and webbeans jar file as per what they found in the logs...the open web beans version is 1.1.0 and im not sure about javassist in openwebbeans in websphere but the version 3.21.0-GA is the javassist implementation on the platform.

Comment: Your question is suffering from the lack of code, ideally an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) making the problem reproducible. This is why you would have to be very lucky to get a correct answer here. It would be pure guesswork or a lucky punch, meeting someone here with the exact same problem, which I think is quite unlikely. I think you need to improve the question.

Comment: ok @kriegaex ill try to modify it

Comment: I do not see any edits.

Answer (score 0):

At present, i am working whit migration from WAS to Websphere liberty base and I have had this issue. In my case, i solved this problem excluding javassist dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
                <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

Best regards.